# Identifying kalpana swaram ragam in the RTP by Ganesh and Kumaresh in *Samarpanam*

Tags: instrumental, indian-classical, raga

The Carnatic violin duo [Ganesh and Kumaresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_and_Kumaresh) released an album titled *Samarpanam* in 1999, Shruthilaya Audio Recording, in which they play 6 songs. The fourth is a [*Ragam Tanam Pallavi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragam_Thanam_Pallavi) ("Isai kelada") in the ragam *Kānada* set to [*Ādi talam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_tala).

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVp4aZKU0S8) a link to the RTP on YouTube. They play [*kalpana swarams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpanaswaram) in various ragams for the pallavi from approximately 15:30 mins onwards. I am able to identify all the ragams except the last one, and was hoping someone here could help me out.

The other ragams they play kalpana swarams in are as follows, in order:

1. Neelāmbari (15:33)
2. Ranjani (16:26)
3. Revati (17:21)
4. Mohanakalyāni (18:13)
5. Behāg (19:06)
6. **Unable to identify** (20:06)

The main ragam (Kānada) resumes at 21:10 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ragam is *Mahati*, an invention of [Dr. M. Balamuralikrishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Balamuralikrishna). The arohanam and avarohanam is as follows:

**Arohanam:** S G3 P N2 S

**Avarohanam:** S N2 P G3 S

This is a rare example of a ragam employing only 4 swarams in both the arohanam and avarohanam! Dr. Balamuralikrishna has composed a song "Mahaneeya Madhura Moorte" in this ragam set to *Khanda Chāpu tālam*.

You can listen to Dr. Balamuralikrishna sing his composition [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdnOrREDpRs).